# Cross compiling opencv project for ARM

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, cross-compiling

How do I cross compile my opencv C++ program for ARM?

I have successfully compiled opencv for ARM, But I haven't run

> make install

my understanding is that doing this will move the compiled opencv in my system directories. I already have opencv built and installed for my system. Will installing opencv compiled for ARM mess up my native opencv?

When I compile opencv project for my system I specify the opencv Library Path and header directories with -L and -I options. I want to compile the same project for arm, how do i go about doing this.

Comment: Typically when cross-compiling, you set a "prefix" or some such, that determines where `make install` will install things (at `${prefix}/{bin,lib,include,docs}`, so you can choose where the resulting code is installed. That would indeed prevent it from conflicting with your native installation. If you didn't do this, then you probably need to rebuild it. Obviously, when cross-compiling your own applciation you need to use `${prefix}/lib` for the `-L` option and `${prefix}/include` for the `-I` option.

Comment: Have you already tried [Builroot](http://nightly.buildroot.org/manual.html#_about_buildroot)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a simple

> make install

installs the OpenCV in the build directory inside a 'install' folder.

Works only for opencv versions above 2.4.x